# Java netbeans project does not take effect of changes

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans6.7

I have a netbeans project (java desktop application) and I opened it after 2 months. It includes a tabbedpane.
When I tried to add a new choice as a new tab although it appears good in design view when I run it it does not contained the title I gave in the tab.Actually it does not write anything. 
When I tried to change the name in one of the old tabs it does not have any effect when I run it neither. Is there a reasonable answer?

Comment: Could you tell me what does this message means? "\nbproject\build-impl.xml:23: Please build using Ant 1.8.0 or higher. "

Answer (score 0):

As Brian Roach said but also I'd recommend ticking build automatically so you don't have to run the clean and build cycle each time you make changes.

Comment: Could you tell me what does this message means?
"\nbproject\build-impl.xml:23: Please build using Ant 1.8.0 or higher.
"

Comment: It's a build script used by Ant so you'd need to run \nbproject\build-impl.xml through ant. I don't use netbeans much but I presume there's a plugin allowing you to change the build configuration for your project to be run through ant.